# Django Create Array in Django models

Tags: python-3.x, list, django-models, django-rest-framework, jsonparser

I want to create Django model for below data:
How can I create array for `activity_periods` and members ?

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "members": [{
            "id": "W012A3CDE",
            "real_name": "Egon Spengler",
            "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "activity_periods": [{
                    "start_time": "Feb 1 2020  1:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Feb 1 2020 1:54PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 1 2020  11:11AM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 1 2020 2:00PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 16 2020  5:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 16 2020 8:02PM"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "W07QCRPA4",
            "real_name": "Glinda Southgood",
            "tz": "Asia/Kolkata",
            "activity_periods": [{
                    "start_time": "Feb 1 2020  1:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Feb 1 2020 1:54PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 1 2020  11:11AM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 1 2020 2:00PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 16 2020  5:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 16 2020 8:02PM"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Can you please post where you are so far, have you checked django documentation on creating models in general? I hope you find the help you need, if you have any code please post it or try editing your question to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a use-case for `ForeignKey`

```
from timezone_field import TimeZoneField

class Member(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField()
   real_name = models.CherField()
   tz = TimeZoneField(default='Europe/London')

class Period(models.Model):
   member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   start = models.DateTimeField()
   end = models.DateTimeField()
```

By this, you will be able to write `Period`-specific methods (ex : compute time range)